# No imprime bien los resultados

Tags: python, lista

Mi problema está casi resuelto, solo falta algo

```
l=[]
n=str(input("Ingrese nombres.presione -1 para terminar"))
l.append(n)
while n!= '-1':
    n=str(input("Ingrese nombres. presione-1 para terminar"))
    l.append(n)
l.pop()
print(l)
c=0
for x in range(0,len(l)+1,2):
    c+=1
    l.insert(x,c)
print(l)
```

Ese el codigo como tal, y el resultado seria:

```
['pepe','pepe2','pepe3']
[1,'pepe',2,'pepe2',3,'pepe3']
```

Lo que a mi me sale es:

```
['pepe','pepe2','pepe3']
[1,'pepe',2,'pepe2','pepe3']
```

No envia el ultimo numero que seria el 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = []
n = None
while True:
    try:
        entrada = str(input("Ingrese nombres.presione -1 para terminar: "))
        if entrada == "-1":
            break
        elif type(entrada) == str:
            l.append(entrada)
    except:
        pass

print(l)

c = 0
for x in range(len(l)*2):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        c += 1
        l.insert(x, c)

print(l)
```

El bucle `for` tiene que ir desde 0 hasta el doble de la longitud de la lista `l`, ya que al introducir el número delante de cada nombre la longitud de la lista, `len(l)`, se duplica.

El resultado es:

```
['pepe', 'pepe2', 'pepe3']
[1, 'pepe', 2, 'pepe2', 3, 'pepe3']
```

Comment: Gracias. la respuesta ayudo

Answer (score 1):

Porque el límite final `stop` de un [`range(start,stop,step)`](https://docs.python.org/es/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#range) es `exclusive`. Volvele a sumar uno ( 1 + 1  , por el arreglo de longitud vs indice, y por el exlcusive ) al `stop`.

```
for x in range(0,len(l)+2,2):
    c+=1
    l.insert(x,c)
print(l)
```

#### Comprobación

```
Ingrese nombres.presione -1 para terminar>? pepe
Ingrese nombres. presione-1 para terminar>? pepe2
Ingrese nombres. presione-1 para terminar>? pepe3
Ingrese nombres. presione-1 para terminar>? -1
['pepe', 'pepe2', 'pepe3']
[1, 'pepe', 2, 'pepe2', 3, 'pepe3']
```

Comment: No entiendo bien, tu codigo. puedes explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Disculpa error al pegar, ahora si la comprobación es correcta.  En la parte de codigo solo he pegado lo que afecta a la modificacion, el resto es correcto